# Node.js mysql.createConnection vs mysql.Client

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have run across both methods to create mysql connections with Node.js

What is the difference?

Comment: To what Node modules are you referring?

Comment: I think `Client` was the way to setup a connection in older versions of [`node-mysql`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), but is has been superseded by `createConnection`.

Comment: @adrianp im referring to the mysql module